# need to get data for choice fields in Django form a loop?

Tags: python, django

The choice field required in django is in the following format

```
new_choices = (
    (1, 'Data 1'),
    (2, 'Data 2'),
    (3, 'Data 3'),
    (4, 'Data 4'),
    (5, 'Data 5'),
    (6, 'Data 6'),
    (7, 'Data 7'),
     )
```

I am trying to get the data from db but the data is not getting properly

```
        CHOICES =  heads.objects.filter(brcd=self.n_brcd, status=1, acmast=1)
        test =([('(' + str(p.head) + '-' + p.detail + ')') for p in CHOICES])
        len_of_test = len(test)
        
        new_choices =[]
        for n in range(len_of_test):
         new_choices = '(' + str(n) + "," + test[n] + ')'
```

The output I am getting from the above code is

```
new_choices = ['(0,(Data 0))','(1,(Data 1))','(2,(Data 2))',...]
```

need to get the output as below

```
 new_choices = (
    (1, 'Data 1'),
    (2, 'Data 2'),
    (3, 'Data 3'),
    (4, 'Data 4'),
    (5, 'Data 5'),
    (6, 'Data 6'),
    (7, 'Data 7'),
     )
```

Comment: If you use this for a form, it is better to work with a `ModelChoiceFIeld`.

Comment: The data format is messed up , I can't get it match the syntax of choice fields

Comment: but a `ModelChoiceField` works with a queryset, and thus abstracts away the logic to select an option. It also makes no sense to work with `0`, `1`, since the primary keys of the details are differently at the database end.

Comment: When I use the the queyset it is showing the following error "cannot unpack non-iterable data object"

Comment: not as `choices=...` for a `ChoiceField`, as the `queryset=...` parameter of a `ModelChoiceField`

Comment: I was adding the choices during the __init__ of project because of some specific requiremnts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a list of 2-tuples with:

```
CHOICES =  heads.objects.filter(brcd=self.n_brcd, status=1, acmast=1)
new_choices = [
    (i, f'{p.head}-{p.detail}')
    for i, p in enumerate(CHOICES, 1)
]
```

But populating data from a `QuerySet` often is not necessary. Usually a `ModelChoiceField` is used to pick an element for a `ForeignKey`.

That being said, you probably are looking for a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) which is a `ChoiceField` populated by a queryset.

Answer (score 2):

As Willem Van Onsem notes in a comment, you should probably use database IDs instead of 0,1,... as the keys in the list of choices.

I would use an approach like the following:

```
qs = heads.objects.filter(brcd=self.n_brcd, status=1, acmast=1)
new_choices = []
for p in qs:
    label = '(' + str(p.head) + '-' + p.detail + ')'
    new_choices.append((p.id, label))
```